# How do I verify that an NUnit Addin has been loaded?

Tags: nunit, add-in

From what I can tell, the assembly containing the addin must be located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.7\bin\net-2.0\addins`. I think my assembly is being loaded because I have to close NUnit-gui before I can replace the assembly in the addins directory. The problem, however, is that I don't see any of the effects of the addin (None of the event handlers are being called)

So **how do I verify that my addin has been loaded?** I'd love to step through with the debugger but I'd be perfectly happy with print line debugging. When I tried doing a `File.WriteAllText()` the addin failed to load but gave no reason. Also, **how do I debug the loading process?**

The [NUnit docs](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunitAddins&r=2.5.7) are helpful, but they're bare bones at best when it comes to extensibility and there isn't any intellisense available for classes in NUnit.Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some tracing library like this [one](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2010/07/04/140761.aspx) which you can download [here](http://apichange.codeplex.com/releases).
Now you can decorate your relevant methods with using statements like this:

```
using ApiChange.Infrastructure;
class MyAddin
{
   static TypeHashes myType = new TypeHashes(typeof(MyAddin);

   void RelevantMethod()
   {
       using (Tracer t = new Tracer(myType, "RelevantMethod"))
       {
           ....
           if(bLoaded == false)
             t.Error("Could not load adding because of {0}", reason);
       }
   }
}
```

Then you can enable tracing via the environment variable _TRACE

```
set _Trace=debugoutput
```

DebugOutput can be viewed with the SysInternals tool [DbgView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) (no attach simply start it and watch the traces). 
Or you trace to a file

```
set _Trace=file
```

The trace file is located where the executable is e.g. Nunit.exe.txt. If you set _TRACE to some random string it will trace the help to console and OutputDebugString to give you help.

Why this trace library? It is actually the ONLY one which is able to trace any exception when your method is left. This does work when the method contains using statements for tracing like the one above.  If it is actually your fault that NUnit does choose to ignore your plugin you can find out now. 
The output will look like this:

> ***** ApiChange.IntegrationTests.Diagnostics.TracingTests.Demo_Show_Leaving_Trace_With_Exception
>   18:57:46.665  03064/05180 <{{         > ApiChange.IntegrationTests.Diagnostics.TracingTests.SomeMethod 
>   18:57:46.668  03064/05180 <{{         > ApiChange.IntegrationTests.Diagnostics.TracingTests.SomeOtherMethod 
>   18:57:46.670  03064/05180 <         }}< ApiChange.IntegrationTests.Diagnostics.TracingTests.SomeOtherMethod Exception thrown: System.NotImplementedException: Hi this a fault
>      at ApiChange.IntegrationTests.Diagnostics.TracingTests.FaultyMethod()
>      at ApiChange.IntegrationTests.Diagnostics.TracingTests.SomeOtherMethod()
>      at ApiChange.IntegrationTests.Diagnostics.TracingTests.SomeMethod()
>      at ApiChange.IntegrationTests.Diagnostics.TracingTests.Demo_Show_Leaving_Trace_With_Exception()
>   18:57:46.670  03064/05180 <         }}< ApiChange.IntegrationTests.Diagnostics.TracingTests.SomeOtherMethod Duration 2ms
>   18:57:46.689  03064/05180 <         }}< ApiChange.IntegrationTests.Diagnostics.TracingTests.SomeMethod Duration 24ms

That should make it easy to find out why your Addin was not used at all. And you do not need a debugger ;-).

Yours,
   Alois Kraus

Comment: Did it work? Besides the hints above you only need to download the 1.0.0.1 release and add a reference to ApiChange.Api.dll to get tracing to work.